# Wrap contextual html around a specific twig variable {{ product.name }}

Tags: twig, twig-extension

I want to automatically wrap some html, lets say `<span data-id="..">` when I call `{{ product.name }}` in my twig template.

So when in a twig template, I use `{{ product.name }}`, I want the output to be: `<span data-type="product" data-id="8" data-prop="name">My product name</span>`. I cannot use twig filters or macros, since I really need the template syntax to be `{{ product.name }}`, so the end-user (template designer), does not have to care about it.

The reason I need this is because I am building an on-page editting tool for twig templates, so I need to know the contexts of those variables from within HTML.

I have tried to override the `Compiler` that the `Twig_Environment` uses, but I cannot seem to alter the output of the twig variable node.

How can I do this?

**EDIT**

I wanted to mention that I need this to use the `{{ product.name }}` syntax, since other designers will work with those templates outside of Symfony 2. I want to make almost all twig variables editable in the front-end, so a solution with filters or macros can indeed work, but it kills the usability and readability of the platform I am writing. There is no public API currently in twig that can achieve what I want, that is why I am fiddling with the twig compiler. I do not have the required knowledge of the Twig internals to achieve this. If someone could point me into a direction that would be great!

**UPDATE 2**

I have found a place where I can achieve what I want. Every `GetAttr` node is compiled to `$this->getAttribute($someContext, "property")`. So if I can change the subclass of compiled twig template, I can achieve what I want. By default all twig templates extend from `Twig_Template`. I want to extend [this method](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/blob/604e94883bc1691071d9a30ff522808dc476394c/lib/Twig/Template.php#L456).

How can I change the subclass of all compiled twig templates?

**UPDATE 3**
I've found a way to use my own base class for all compiled twig templates. I can simply set it as an option on the twig environment, see [this link](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/api.html#environment-options). I hope to get it working tomorrow and I will post a proper answer on how I solved it all together. Not sure how I will handle escaping, since that will happen after the `$this->getAttribute()` is called.

Comment: Have you tried to write a twig extension? Which problem do you have?

Comment: Yes I did, but there I only have the context of the whole file. But what I need is the context that is given to the `GetAttr` node and use the property that it is trying to get out of it for the final twig output. When I extend the compiler I can use the `subcompile` method to get to those nodes, but I cannot find a way to alter the output of those. My knowledge for the internals of twig are not enough to accomplish what I want.

Comment: Why the downvote? If my question is not clear, please say so, so I can try to explain it better.

Comment: probably because is not clear what you have tried to do

Comment: Hi Steffen, what do you think about my answer?

Comment: @Matteo Thanks for helping, i've updated my question and also made some progress with my issue! I am afraid I cannot use filters not macros, so the easy solutions won't fit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've solved it by wrapping the `PrintNode` that is created when parsing a `VAR_START` token (inside the twig parser) with my own `EditablePrintNode`. In that node I traverse the expression that is compiled by the print node and get the necessary property path and pass that as an argument to a wrapper function around the default twig escape function that is compiled by the `PrintNode`.

Comment: Care to share the code? I am looking to solve a similar problem, and an illustration of your solution would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I think [macros](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/macro.html) are the best candidates for those kind of wrappings.

For example:

<kbd>main.twig</kbd>

```
{% import "macros.twig" as macros %}

{{ macros.display_product(product) }}
```

<kbd>macros.twig</kbd>

```
{% macro display_product(product) %}

  <span data-id="{{ product.id }}" data-prop="name">{{ product.name }}</span>

{% endmacro %}
```

<kbd>Context</kbd>

```
product:
     id: 8
     name: My Georgeous Product
```

<kbd>Result</kbd>

```
<span data-id="8" data-prop="name">My Georgeous Product</span>
```

See [fiddle](http://twigfiddle.com/4k0b9a)

Comment: Hi @Alain seems macro sounds better approach instead of a twig filter. +1

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to write a custom filter. You can find the doc [here](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/advanced.html#filters) about how to write and configure in your environment

```
// an anonymous function
$filter = new Twig_SimpleFilter('my_custom_product_filter', function ($product) {
    return '<span data-id="'.$product->getId().'" data-prop="name">'.$product->getName().'</span>';
});
```

You need to register as described in the doc

then you can use as follow:

```
{{ myProduct|my_custom_product_filter}}
```

Hope this help